# Buying Mozart balls at a decent price in Vienna

Tags: food-and-drink, austria, vienna, souvenirs

I'm now leaving from Vienna and I want to bring back home some nice souvenir.
And so... What's better than Mozart balls?

However last time I was here I was buying them at the airport and the price was...well.. how to say? Not a nice price, let it put this way.

So, I was wondering if there is any shop downtown where I can buy them at a good price.
Any hint?

Comment: Buy only at supermarkets in Vienna like ALDI,SPAR if you are looking for decent price. Tourist areas are quite expensive.

Comment: There is no Aldi in Vienna.... It is called Hofer in Austria!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mozartkugel (Mozart rounds) are very popular for tourists - you can buy them almost everywhere - but unfortunately they are not cheap. On [the official page](http://www.mozartkugel.at/?sc_lang=en) you can find a link to an [online shop](http://www.austriansupermarket.com/mirabell-mozart-rounds) and I don’t think the prices will be much lower than that at the airport or in downtown Vienna. A box of 18 pieces costs around €8; that was also the price I paid in Salzburg two months ago.

And by the way, Mozartkugel is more typical for Salzburg than for Vienna.

Comment: Thanks for the precious info. I just found a special offer https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/94x94q90/c/r/661/xuEXC3.jpg   18 balls for 6 €

Comment: PS the special offer was at airport

Comment: @DanieleB You might want to call them something else than “balls”, sounds a bit odd.

Comment: @Relaxed Uh... Right... Can you suggest an alternative? Mozart chocolate candies? BTW I think that the ambiguous meaning of 'balls' is what make them fun and attractive for tourists 

Comment: In the online shop they are called "Mozart rounds", however on http://www.mozartkugel.at/produkte/perfektes_souvenir they alsa call it balls :)

Comment: Always heard them be called Mozart balls in their English-French-Italian translations.

Comment: I would stay with 'Mozart balls' sentence... After all he was a man (read 'male') so it perfectly fits. 

Comment: Can't help to read that as Mozzarella balls. Maybe I'm hungry.

Answer (score 7):

I bought the 343 gr. Mozartkugeln pack with **20 balls** at [Hofer](https://www.hofer.at/) (Austrian ALDI) in Vienna for **€3.88**! I think it's the best price you can get, and they are really delicious.

### The receipt:

[image]

### The ballzz:

[image]

Comment: But note that they are from a different company and also taste different.

Comment: What do you mean by "they"? Do you mean that the expensive ones in tourist traps taste more like Mozart balls than the ones at supermarket? Because first of all, I don't agree with that, and secondly, OP didn't define what company should produce the Mozart balls.

Comment: The Mozart balls sold at Hofer are clearly made from cheaper ingredients and tast different than either of the ["well known" manufacturers](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Mozartkugel_Komposit.jpg).
If you like them, that's ok. I just added the note that they might not be what one expects.

Comment: As I said already, OP is just interested in cheaper Mozart balls. That said, having tasted both expensive and cheap ones, I found both of them tasty, and absolutely recommendable.